# Can't boot into Ubuntu after install

Tags: boot, uefi

I'm new to Ubuntu and can't seem to get Ubuntu to boot off my SSD.
I have Toshiba Satellite P50-A with UEFI, on which I would like to install Ubuntu. I would like to remove Windows.

I have installed Ubuntu via ISO and all partitions have been created.

Boot Repair output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15338133/

Any solutions?

Comment: What symptoms are you seeing? For instance, do you see a purple Ubuntu splash screen that hangs, or does it crash before then? A *complete* description of what happens is necessary for more than a stab-in-the-dark answer.

Answer (score 0):

As per your pastebin contents

**SecureBoot enabled**

Try disabling secureboot in the BIOS and then try login into Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: I have disabled the Secure Boot.

Comment: add i get failed to boot then Inset boot Media

Comment: My HP laptop has a two step process to disable secure boot in BIOS...i was under the impression that secureboot is disabled and was getting similar kind of errors...when i completed two step process to disable secureboot i was successful after that.

Comment: @ThomasPearson. In that case make sure that boot sequence in your BIOS is correct - your drive(SSD) which contains the /boot should be the first device to boot then USB and other media.

Comment: by the second process do you mean changing the UEFI boot to CSM boot,  after disabling?

Comment: Yes the boot order is set up correctly

Comment: Your windows is already removed. I hope you have the recovery drive(or USB) for that. You can try installing Ubuntu once again.

Comment: I have window on the old hdd. I have tried installing multiple times

Comment: Secure Boot is almost certainly ***NOT*** the problem. If it were, the installer would probably not have booted, since the installer and the final installed system use the same boot loaders (Shim and GRUB), signed in the same way. Thomas, your OS is installed in EFI mode, so you should *NOT* enable the CSM/legacy boot support; doing so will do no good at best and could create significant complications at worst.